# Composer not updating on server, requires php though I have it installed

Tags: php, composer-php

When running "composer update" on my server I got this error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package php could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package php could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for phpmailer/phpmailer v5.2.7 -> satisfiable by phpmailer/phpmailer[v5.2.7].
    - phpmailer/phpmailer v5.2.7 requires php >=5.0.0 -> no matching package found.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for gabordemooij/redbean dev-master -> satisfiable by gabordemooij/redbean[dev-master].
    - gabordemooij/redbean dev-master requires php >=5.2.0 -> no matching package found.
  Problem 5
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 3.7.28 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[3.7.28].
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.7.28 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
  Problem 6
    - Installation request for mikey179/vfsstream v1.2.0 -> satisfiable by mikey179/vfsStream[v1.2.0].
    - mikey179/vfsStream v1.2.0 requires php >=5.3.0 -> no matching package found.
  Problem 7
    - phpunit/phpunit-selenium dev-master requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
    - phpunit/phpunit-selenium 1.3.3 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
    - phpunit/phpunit-selenium 1.3.2 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
    - phpunit/phpunit-selenium 1.3.1 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
    - phpunit/phpunit-selenium 1.3.0 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
    - phpunit/phpunit-selenium 1.2.9 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
    - phpunit/phpunit-selenium 1.2.12 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
    - phpunit/phpunit-selenium 1.2.11 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
    - phpunit/phpunit-selenium 1.2.10 requires php >=5.3.3 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit-selenium >=1.2 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit-selenium[1.2.10, 1.2.11, 1.2.12, 1.2.9, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, dev-master].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

It suggested me to install php >=5.3.3, but running php -v on server got me:

```
PHP 5.4.21 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2013 01:52:12) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by ionCube Ltd.
```

Which means I should have had the correct php requirements. Why the error, then?

Comment: Can you run the update command with --verbose and show the output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Composer: The requested package php could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619540/composer-the-requested-package-php-could-not-be-found)

Comment: Indeed... can you also show your composer.json?

Answer (score 0):

When I had a problem like this on another server, I deleted the **vendors** folder and deleted the **composer.lock** through SSH then did a fresh install.